# building blocks

Tags: education

My little sister used her alphabet blocks to build a wall 8 blocks long, 8 blocks high, and 2 blocks wide. This took her 8 minutes. At this rate how long would it take her to build a wall 4 blocks long, 4 blocks high, 1 block wide?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that times depends on the number of blocks we have that in 8 min she disposes 8*8*2= 128 blocks.
The second setup involves 4*4*1=16  blocks.
The solution is obtained via this proportion:
$$x:16=8:128$$
That is x=1 minute.